# Python Multiprocessing Cassandra Connections

Tags: python, cassandra, multiprocessing

I am trying to multiprocess my Cassandra connections.

I have used multiprocessing with queues in simpler cases using the Multiprocessing Queues (pass the child process a bunch of numbers and get results).

In my current DataGetter, I import a Cassandra worker class. Does Python Multiprocessing have any issues with just using previously imported objects?

Here is the relevant code from my DataGetter:

```
def read_data_multi(self, cass_worker, work_queue, done_queue):
    #cass_worker = cbcassandra.CBcassandra(self.chost, self.keyspace)
    cass_worker.open_cur()
    for inq in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        data = self.read_data(cass_worker, inq[0], inq[1], inq[2], inq[3])
        print data
        done_queue.put(data)
    cass.close_cur()
    return True

def multi_get(self, readtype, dcname, vmname, timebucket_list):
    workers = 2
    work_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()
    processes = []

    for tb in timebucket_list:
        inq = (readtype, dcname, vmname, tb)
        print inq
        work_queue.put(inq)

    for w in xrange(workers):
        cass_worker = cbcassandra.CBcassandra(self.chost, self.keyspace)
        p = Process(target=self.read_data_multi, args=(cass_worker, work_queue, done_queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        work_queue.put('STOP')
    print processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    done_queue.put('STOP')
    return done_queue
```

`read_data` works perfectly when I am *not* using multiprocessing.

Here is my output when using multiprocessing. My processes start, but they cannot make a connection:

```
[<Process(Process-1, started)>, <Process(Process-2, started)>]  
Process Process-1:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap 
self.run()  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)  
File "preparedata.py", line 251, in read_data_multi  
cass_worker.open_cur()  
File "/root/cbcassandra.py", line 40, in open_cur 
cluster, cur = self.getclustsess(self.keyspace)  
File "/root/cbcassandra.py", line 33, in getclustsess
session = cluster.connect(keyspace)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 471, in connect
self.control_connection.connect()  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1355, in connect
self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1390, in _reconnect_internal  
raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'104.130.65.178': OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection, last_host=None',)})  
Process Process-2:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap 
self.run()  
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)  
File "preparedata.py", line 251, in read_data_multi
cass_worker.open_cur()  
File "/root/cbcassandra.py", line 40, in open_cur
cluster, cur = self.getclustsess(self.keyspace)  
File "/root/cbcassandra.py", line 33, in getclustsess
session = cluster.connect(keyspace)  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 471, in connect
self.control_connection.connect()  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1355, in connect
self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())  
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1390, in _reconnect_internal  
raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)  
NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'104.130.65.178':   OperationTimedOut('errors=Timed out creating connection, last_host=None',)})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out today that multiprocessing with cassandra requires closing cassandra session/cluster before a new process start, which is the similar to django.db connection in multiprocess.

e.g:

```
cass_worker.session.cluster.shutdown()
cass_worker.session.shutdown()
cass_worker = cbcassandra.CBcassandra(self.chost, self.keyspace)
```

Comment: What is CBcassandra? Was unable to find anything about it.